# Why does Python enforce change in size during iteration for dict, but not for list?

Tags: python

*This question is not a duplicate of [Dictionary changed size during iteration - Code works in Py2 Not in Py3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830124). This question asks why this is not enforced for `list`, not how to fix the code.*

Python will happily execute

```
li = [1, 2, 3]
for n in li:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        li.remove(n)
```

But if we try with a dict:

```
a = {1: '', 2: '', 3: ''}   
for n in a:                 
    if n % 2 == 0:          
        a.pop(n)
```

We get

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Since I assume this is an implementation detail, I'll note that this was tested with CPython 3.7.0 and 3.4.2.

Comment: That's not a suitable duplicate. This is a "why?" question, not a "how do I make it work in python 3" question. The answers there don't explain why this exception is thrown.

Comment: In the linked answer it did provide the why though.  `iter(a)` is providing a `dict_keyiterator` view and the view itself doesn't function like a `list`.  Unless the question is, why doesn't `view` objects allow for changes during iteration... which I can surmise is due to it being a view-copy of the orig object.

Comment: [PEP 3106](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/) discusses the motivation

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because a `dict` is a more complicated structure that is much harder to iterate when it changes.

Comment: The check has been there since the [original iterator commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/59d1d2b434e8cf79e8b1321f148254c68f56c1f7), with no explanation in the commit message. If I had to guess, I'd say they put the check in for dicts because they *could*, whereas they couldn't with lists because of backward compatibility with the old `__getitem__` iteration.

Comment: I believe the dupe is right this time.  I actually had an answeretyped up but if OP is not happy with the dupe I can post it.  The [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) shows that these dict-views are "Set-like" and behaves much like a `set` when changed during iteration.