# problem in fantasy game inventory program (RuntimeError: dictionary size changed during iteration)

Tags: python, dictionary, runtime-error

I'm working on a problem given in chapter 5 of the book *Automate Boring Stuff with Python* in which I have to define a function (`addToInventory`) which is supposed to add items in a list (named `dragonLoot`) to a dictionary (called `inv`) and another function (`displayInventory`) which is supposed to display the new dictionary (`inv`). The `displayInventory` function works fine when I test it separately, but when I run the complete program I'm getting `RuntimeError: dictionary size changed during iteration`. Here is my code:

```
def displayInventory(inv):
    for k,j in inv.items(): #to display inv in format of a game inventory
        print(k,end=':')
        print(j)
def addToInventory(inv,dragonLoot):
    for a,b in inv.items(): #a represents key and b represents values
        for c in range(len(dragonLoot)-1):
            if a==dragonLoot[c]: #to check items in dragonLoot
                b+=1 #adding 1 to value if its corresponding key exists in dragonloot
            else:
                inv.setdefault(dragonLoot[c],1) #adding the new item if it dosent exist in dragonLoot 
    return inv
inv = {'gold coin':42,'rope':1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin','dagger','gold coin','gold coin','ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv,dragonLoot)
displayInventory(inv)
```

here is the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\murali\mu_code\addtoinventory.py", line 16, in <module>
    inv = addToInventory(inv,dragonLoot)
  File "c:\users\murali\mu_code\addtoinventory.py", line 7, in addToInventory
    for a,b in inv.items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

please tell me where I'm making a mistake and also what kind of mistakes can cause such error.I have also found different solution to this problem but i want to know problem in this program.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You are not allowed to change the dictionary that you are iterating over. In your case that would be `inv`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dictionary changed size during iteration - Code works in Py2 Not in Py3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830124/dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-code-works-in-py2-not-in-py3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having has to do with calling `setdefault` on your dictionary (which might add a new item to it) while you're already iterating over the dictionary's `items`. But there's really no reason for you to be iterating. Dictionaries are most powerful when you're *indexing* them with a key to see what their value is. Iterating over all the keys is much less efficient.

Here's how I'd do it. First we have only one loop, over the `dragonLoot` sequence. We don't need to mess with a `range` to get an index here, just naming the list directly will let us iterate directly over its items. The `get` method on the dictionary does some indexing, checking if the key is in the dictionary, and it either returns to us the associated existing value, or a default value we give it (as the second argument to `get`, `0` in this case). Finally, we add one to the value, and do an assignment back to the dictionary, using the loot item as the key again:

```
def addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot):
    for loot_item in dragonLoot:
        inv[loot_item] = inv.get(loot_item, 0) + 1
    return inv
```